# C# - Find LoginView Control within MultiView

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

How to access `LoginView1` control inside `Multiview1`, `View2`?

I have a some textbox and dropdownlist in loggedIn template of View 2 within Multiview, I need to get the control and bind with text from database.

I had try:

```
((TextBox)this.LoginView1.FindControl("custEmail")).Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("custEmail")).Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("custEmail")).Text = "xxxx";
```

return "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Markup Code

```
<asp:View ID="View2" runat="server" OnActivate="login_Click">
                <asp:Label ID="tprice" runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                            <AnonymousTemplate>
                                Please login to continue.<br />
                                <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
                                    <LayoutTemplate>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                                        CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                                        CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <asp:Button ID="login" runat="server" CommandName="Login" OnCommand="login_Click"
                                                Text="Log in"
                                                CssClass="btn btn-info" />
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FailureText" class="validation-summary-errors" />
                                    </LayoutTemplate>
                                </asp:Login>
                                or
                        <a id="registerLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a>&nbsp;
                        to continue
                            </AnonymousTemplate>
                            <LoggedInTemplate>
                                <table class="custable">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" AssociatedControlID="title" runat="server" Text="Title : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="title" runat="server">
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select One...</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="Mr">Mr</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="Mrs">Mrs</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="Miss">Miss</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="Ms">Ms</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="Doctor">Doctor</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server"
                                                ControlToValidate="title" ValueToCompare="0" Operator="NotEqual"
                                                Text="Please select the title." CssClass="field-validation-error"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" AssociatedControlID="name" runat="server" Text="Full Name As Per IC : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" Text="*Required"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" AssociatedControlID="custEmail" runat="server" Text="Email : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="custEmail" runat="server" TextMode="Email" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="custEmail"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" Text="*"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" AssociatedControlID="email2" runat="server" Text="Confirm Email : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="email2" runat="server" TextMode="Email" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" ControlToCompare="email2" ControlToValidate="custEmail"
                                                runat="server"
                                                Operator="Equal" Type="String" Text="Please enter same Email." CssClass="field-validation-error"
                                                ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" AssociatedControlID="icPassport" runat="server" Text="IC / Passport : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="icPassport" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="icPassport"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" Text="*"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label10" AssociatedControlID="mobile" runat="server" Text="Mobile : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="mobile" runat="server" placeholder="60123456789" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="mobile"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" Text="*"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" /><br />
                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="mobile"
                                                Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double" ErrorMessage="Mobile number must be integer."
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ValidationGroup="vg1" Display="None" /><br />
                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="mobile"
                                                ErrorMessage="Mobile Number must within 10 to 18 digits." ValidationExpression="^\d{10,18}$"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ValidationGroup="vg1" Display="None" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" AssociatedControlID="street" runat="server" Text="Street : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="street" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="street"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" Text="*"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label12" AssociatedControlID="townstate" runat="server" Text="Town / State : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="townstate" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="townstate"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" Text="*"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label13" AssociatedControlID="country" runat="server" Text="Country : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="country" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator4" runat="server"
                                                ControlToValidate="country" ValueToCompare="Select One..." Type="String" Operator="NotEqual"
                                                Text="*" CssClass="field-validation-error"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label14" AssociatedControlID="postalcode" runat="server" Text="Postal Code : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="postalcode" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="postalcode"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" Text="*"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" /><br />
                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="postalcode"
                                                Type="Integer" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Postal Code must be integer."
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ValidationGroup="vg1" Display="none" /><br />
                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="postalcode"
                                                ErrorMessage="Postal Code, 5 or 9 Digits." ValidationExpression="\d{5}?(\d{4})?$"
                                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ValidationGroup="vg1" Display="None" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label15" AssociatedControlID="yearOfBirth" runat="server" Text="Year Of Birth : " />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="yearOfBirth" runat="server">
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Year</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator6" runat="server"
                                                ControlToValidate="yearOfBirth" ValueToCompare="0" Operator="NotEqual"
                                                Text="*" CssClass="field-validation-error"
                                                SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </LoggedInTemplate>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Next" CommandName="NextView" runat="server" />
            </asp:View>
```

C# Code Behind

```
protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string userId = (Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey).ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string selectcmd = "select Email from Memberships where userID='" + userId + "'";
            string selectcmd2 = "select custEmail, title, name, icPassport, mobile, street, townstate, postalcode, townstate, yearOfBirth from custInfo where userID='" + userId + "'";

            SqlDataReader dr;
            cmd = new SqlCommand(selectcmd2, con);
            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    ((TextBox)this.LoginView1.FindControl("custEmail")).Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    ((DropDownList)LoginView1.FindControl("title")).SelectedValue = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    ((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("name")).Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    ((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("icPassport")).Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    ((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("mobile")).Text = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    ((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("street")).Text = dr.GetValue(6).ToString();
                    ((DropDownList)LoginView1.FindControl("townstate")).SelectedValue = dr.GetValue(7).ToString();
                    ((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("postalcode")).Text = dr.GetValue(8).ToString().Trim();
                    ((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("townstate")).Text = dr.GetValue(9).ToString();
                    ((DropDownList)LoginView1.FindControl("yearOfBirth")).SelectedValue = dr.GetValue(10).ToString();
                }
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                dr.Close();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(selectcmd, con);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    (this.LoginView1.FindControl("custEmail") as TextBox).Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                }
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that FindControl searches only the current level If you want to search in the branches (inside a MultiView, Panel, PlaceHolder, etc.) as well then you have to use some kind of recursive search.

First find the control in multiview control and by using MultiView.FindControl Method and then access the  child controls in that found control

some sample posts

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13836/Find-child-controls-inside-a-MultiView-control-in